# do not send hangup signal to background process when bash exit

Tags: bash, sh

I know when shell exits or itself receives SIGHUP, it will send SIGHUP to all background process.

'nohup cmd' or 'disown' will tell bash not to send SIGHUP. Is there a shell setting so that bash will always not send SIGHUP?

I want my backgroup process to run when bash got killed accidentally for various reasons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to look into `jobs` and `disown`. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html

Comment: It doesn't like the page you mentioned talks about shell option I want. There is only 'huponexit shell option', I need 'nohuponexit'. Thanks.

Comment: `jobs` may in fact be part of the solution.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am looking for a shell setting that will tell bash never to send SIGHUP to background process upon shell exiting. With 'jobs' 'disown', you need to explicitly type something in order for it to happen.